# How to binding combobox to combobox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, .net-4.0, combobox

I have two Combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="sourceNumber">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="4"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="5"/>
```

and

```
<ComboBox x:Name=destinationNumber ItemsSource="{Binding Source={sourceNumber.SelectedIndex}"/>
```

When I select `sourceNumber = 3`  (1,2,3) will be added to `destinationNumber`
When I select `sourceNumber = 5`  (1,2,3,4,5) will be added to `destinationNumber`

How can I do it ? Thanks for helps .

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use converter to solve this problem.

```
public class ComboBoxItemsSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value != null && value is int)
            {
                int max = (int)value;
                if (max == -1) return null;
                return Enumerable.Range(1, max + 1);
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And you must slightly change your XAML code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="destinationNumber" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex, ElementName=sourceNumber, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"/>
```

Where `myConverter` is:

```
<local:ComboBoxItemsSourceConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
```